# Dynamic Interpolation in Angular2

Tags: dynamic, angular, interpolation

I am learning Angular-2 and try to build data-grid component and run into a problem with dynamic interpolation. 
Assume, the other component will consume the data-grid like the following:

```
<data-grid [model] = 'users'>
   <column header='Last Name' value="lastName" ></column>
   <column header='First Name' value='firstName' ></column>
   <column header='Address' value='address' ></column>
</data-grid>
```

The data-grid component holds a collection of columns. From the data-gird, I try to loop through the columns collection to build the column header then show all data. The headers for the table is easy but I don't know how to do the nested interpolation for row and columns.

```
<div class="container" >
    <table class="table table-hover">
         <thead class="thead-default">
             <tr>
                <th template="ngFor let col of columns">
                    {{ col.header}}
                 <th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr template="ngFor let row of model">
               <td template="ngFor let col of columns">
                <!-- want to loop though the columns 
                {{row.{{col.value}}}} //How to make this statement works? -->
              </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>  
    </table>
</div>
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

thanks,

Austin

Comment: also you are using *ngFor in a wrong manner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need the additional evaluation brackets. Use square brackets for array indexing.

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of model">
   <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
       {{row[col.value]}} 
   </td>
</tr>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/DVwolRDu0JNcsXTaTrir

Comment: This seems pretty interesting!

Comment: thanks, it works. However, for complex binding such as                   
<column header='Customer Name' value="lastName,firstName"></column>
I need to be able to interpolation of a  string such as 
"{{row.field1}}, {{row.field2}}}" or to build  then template dynamically.

Comment: you can also define helper methods to perform such lookups
`<td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                  {{getFields(row, col)}}
</td>`

Comment: Thanks,  this is great !